# showing adjacent rows in a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using mvc5 and razor and I have all data required bound to the view.

**View.cs**

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TestTermin)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
            </th>
            <th>
                #Users applied
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var test in Model)
        {
            <tr class="text-left">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test.TestTermin)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test.Location)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @test.Users.Count
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = test.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = test.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = test.ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
            foreach (var user in test.Users)
            {
                <tr class="hideMe" style="display:none">
                    <td>@user.FirstName</td>
                    <td>@user.LastName</td>
                    <td>@user.Email</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

</table>
```

This results in a html like this:

```
<tr class="text-left">
<tr class="hideMe">
<tr class="hideMe">
<tr class="text-left">
<tr class="hideMe">
<tr class="text-left">
```

Is there a way, using jQuery, or something else from the mvc5/razor suite, that can achieve the following:

Clicking on a row, shows the adjacent hidden rows, and on click hides them back again? I do not want to show ALL hidden rows in the table, just the ones that belong to the clicked tr.

I have tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('tr').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('tr').toggle('slow');

    });
</script>
```

but this just shows everything hidden, and hides everything visible which is not the functionally I am after.

Comment: If you click on the first `<tr class="text-left">` do you want to show the following 2 `<tr class="hideMe">` (or just the first one)?

Comment: i want to show the following <tr> as many as they are. TR are dynamically generated so i do not know the number in advance

Comment: It would probably easiest to put each group (the visible row and its associated hidden row(s) in a `<tbody>` element so you can use relative selectors -similar to the answer by Reddy, but `$(this).siblings('tr').toggle('slow');`

Comment: Also it should be `$('tr.text-left').click(...` so that clicking on one of the `class="hideMe"` rows does not screw it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code `$('tr').toggle('slow');` is that the selector `$('tr')` selects all the `tr's` and toggles the display of all the `tr's`. What you need is to just select the next couple of tr's to the current clicked `tr` and toggle its display. You can make use of the **[Jquery .nextUntill()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)** feature.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sv5gvffz/2/)**

```
$('tr.text-left').click(function () {   
    $(this).nextUntil("tr.text-left").toggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: this only shows/hides the next row, which is not the functionally I am after. When I click the test row, I want to see users taking the test. With the code above, I can just see the next row, be it another, already visible test, or just one of many users taking the test.